# Forbidden You don't have permission to access /folder on this server

Tags: php, apache, permissions

I am trying to run a php app but keep getting the

> "Forbidden You don't have permission to access /folder on this server."

I have `Require all granted` uncommented in my httpd.conf and I've also tried setting the permissions with

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$STAFF ~/Sites/secondPHPApp
```

and

```
sudo chmod -R 755 ~/Sites/
```

I have my phpadmin in that file. I can access the phpadmin from the browser and get the *IT WORKS* default page but having trouble accessing my app folder because of the permission issue.

This is my vhost settings in httpd-vhosts.conf (**note:** I do have an actual email and username in the actual file.):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias www.test.com
    ServerAdmin email
    DocumentRoot “/Users/username/Sites/secondPHPApp”
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents/
</VirtualHost>
```

Result of `ls -al ~/Sites`:

```
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 6 755 staff 204 Feb 16 11:00 . 
drwxr-xr-x+ 51 LonnieMcGill staff 1734 Feb 15 14:33 ..
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 755 staff 6148 Feb 16 10:47 .DS_Store
-rwxr-xr-x 1 755 staff 20 Feb 15 09:53 index.php
drwxr-xr-x@ 112 755 staff 3808 Feb 15 13:34 phpmyadmin
lrwxr-xr-x 1 755 staff 60 Feb 16 11:00 secondPHPApp -> /Users/LonnieMcGill/Desktop/Project Folder/php/secondPHPApp/
```

Result of `ls -al ~/Sites/secondPHPApp`:

```
lrwxr-xr-x 1 755 staff 60 Feb 16 11:00 /Users/LonnieMcGill/Sites/secondPHPApp -> /Users/LonnieMcGill/Desktop/Project Folder/php/secondPHPApp/
```

Result of `ls -al ~/Sites/secondPHPApp/index.html`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 LonnieMcGill staff 360 Feb 16 11:02 /Users/LonnieMcGill/Sites/secondPHPApp/index.html
```

Comment: Do you have an index file in your folder? Otherwise if your apache don't allow listing of files, it will show that error message.

Comment: Try to put an `index.html` in your `~/Sites/secondPHPApp`

Comment: I have an index.html file in the folder I am trying to access.

Comment: Can you show us your `vhost` configuration file? Also, what are you typing in your browser? localhost or something else?

Comment: I am typing localhost/secondPHPApp i've also tried localhost/secondPHPApp/index.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135892/discussion-between-chin-leung-and-lonnie-mcgill).

Answer (score 1):

After investigating with Lonnie in the [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135892/discussion-between-chin-leung-and-lonnie-mcgill) for a while, it turns out that it was the french double quote. Since the french double quote and the english double quote is different, apache consider it part of the file path therefore its unable to locate the document root specified in the vhost so it returns a 403 error.

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/username/Sites/secondPHPApp"
```